# dlib: Failing expression was y < output_tensor.k()

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, xor, dlib

dlib 19.13 - Linux Mint 18
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

In an attempt to make an XOR NN with dlib using the code section below:

...

```
std::vector<matrix<unsigned long>> training_set;
std::vector<unsigned long>         training_labels;
std::vector<matrix<unsigned long>> testing_set;
std::vector<unsigned long>         testing_labels;

training_set.push_back( {0,0} );
training_set.push_back( {0,1} );
training_set.push_back( {1,0} );
training_set.push_back( {1,1} );

training_labels.push_back(0);
training_labels.push_back(1);
training_labels.push_back(1);
training_labels.push_back(0);


testing_set.push_back( {0,0} );
testing_set.push_back( {0,1} );
testing_set.push_back( {1,0} );
testing_set.push_back( {1,1} );

testing_labels.push_back(0);
testing_labels.push_back(1);
testing_labels.push_back(1);
testing_labels.push_back(0);


using net_type = loss_multiclass_log<
                            fc<1,        
                            relu<fc<3,   
                            input<matrix<unsigned long>> 
                            >>>>;
```

...

It compiles but I'm getting this output upon execution of my test:

Error detected at line 322.
Error detected in file ../dlib/dnn/loss.h.
Error detected in function double dlib::loss_multiclass_log_::compute_loss_value_and_gradient(const dlib::tensor&, const_label_iterator, SUBNET&) const [with const_label_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; SUBNET = dlib::dimpl::subnet_wrapper, dlib::add_layer, dlib::input >, void>, void>, void>, true, void>].

Failing expression was y < output_tensor.k().
y: 1, output_tensor.k(): 1

Answer (score 2):

I thought the first parameter to the fc class of dlib was the number of output nodes.  But as it turns out, it seems to be the number of possible outputs; So 0 and 1 are two possible output values of that layer.  After changing from 1 to 2 and recompiling the network trains and exhibits 100% accuracy:

```
using net_type = loss_multiclass_log<
                            fc<2,  // <--- changed to 2    
                            relu<fc<3,   
                            input<matrix<unsigned long>> 
                            >>>>;
```